# SSIS OLE DB Command Transformation (Oracle Connection Manager) failing for columns with NUMERIC(28,10) data type?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, visual-studio-2019, oledbcommand

I am having a lot of trouble getting a new SSIS package to work. Overall, it takes an Excel spreadsheet of data (headers, a few rows, maybe 15 columns) and should upload that data into an Oracle DB.

Columns in Oracle are roughly: (2) `NVARCHR2`, (4) `NUMBER(38,0)`, and (9) `NUMBER(28,10)`.

NOTE: I was using Visual Studio 2022, but every time my Excel Connection Manager goes to Validate, the entire application freezes as "busy" until force terminated. Switched to Visual Studio 2019 since I still have it installed on my machine.

Current flow:

Excel Source --> Data Conversion (for Lookup) --> Lookup -->:

1. Rows with No Match in `[Lookup]` get directly inserted
2. Rows with Match in `[Lookup]` exist and therefore need to be updated, go to OLE DB Command transformation.

I can:

- Specify my Oracle `OleDBConnection` manager
- Set the `SqlCommand` property like:

  ```
  UPDATE TABLEXYZ 
  SET Field1 = ?, Field2 = ?, Field3= ?, Field4 = ? 
  WHERE Field5 = ?
  ```
- In [Input and Output Properties] manually add under OLE DB Command Input --> External Columns --> Param_0, Param_1 ... Param_4 and specify data types (this appears to be necessary to do manually when dealing with Oracle as the destination?)

Everything works exactly as expected setting the mapped parameter for my Oracle `NVARCHAR2` columns to string `[DT_WSTR]`, and my `NUMBER (38, 0)` columns to `numeric (18, 0)`.

But as soon as I update my `SqlCommand` and parameter mappings to include an Oracle `NUMBER(28,10)` column, the `OLE DB Command` transformation fails every time. The error from Package execution is seemingly useless but I will include below:

> [OLE DB Command [210]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "".
>
> [OLE DB Command [210]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "OraOLEDB"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "1". (repeats multiple times)
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Command" (210) failed with error code 0xC0202009 while processing input "OLE DB Command Input" (215). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

For the `NUMBER(28,10)` columns, I have tried setting to `Numeric (18, 0)` default, `Numeric (28, 10)`, `Numeric (38, 10)`, `Decimal`, `Currency`, and a few others.

Can anyone more experienced tell me what I am doing wrong and need datatype to specify my "OLE DB Command" parameters to use for an Oracle DB column of type `NUMBER(28,10)`?

Comment: Have you verified that there are no numbers in the spreadsheet with more than 10 decimal places of scale?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server when you are using Oracle?

Comment: @Xedni - I will check, that is a fair point to consider.

Comment: @DaleK - the question relates to SQL Server data types (SSIS) being transferred to Oracle backend.

Comment: Yeah, but overall your question is not something an SQL Server expert can help you with, you need an Oracle expert who knows a bit of SQL Server. I must be missing something, if you are importing from Excel, how do SQL Server datatypes come into it?

Comment: @DaleK - I apologize if I mistagged. I believed the tag accurate as all SSIS development appears to be based (naturally) around SQL server data types and functionality, with a sprinkling of functionality available in the same components for Oracle. Everything read in from the data sheet auto-converts initially to utilize SQL Server data typing, so I thought the reference valid.

Comment: @Xedni - Of the 10 records in my test data sheet, 6 are null for the test Field1 in question, and (4) have values with 11 digits formatted as Currency akin to 88888888888 = $88,888,888,888 or 47671054492 = $47,671,054,492. Does that shed any light?

Comment: Not sure how Oracle parses strings to numbers, but in SQL Server, if you try to cast something like '$88,888' as a decimal, it will fail. You might need to create a derived column which cleans up the non-numeric characters. This is still a bit of a guess, but it's what I'd try to eliminate

Comment: @Xedni I am not sure if this clears things up, but if I upstream in the Data Conversion mark an Available Input Column for conversion, the "Copy" Output Alias of these is by default set to a Data Type of "currency [DT_CY]" which fails if I map the External Column Parameter field as either currency or numeric. However, if I mark the Data Conversion output alias as numeric upstream and then reference that converted column downstream to the External Column Parameter also as numeric, it works? This is not necessary when adding a brand new record, but seems to be required for editing existing?